# Rotating numbers in a 2x3 grid

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

We have a 2x3 grid numbers like so

6 5 4
3 2 1

Four numbers in any 2x2 sub-grid can be rotated clockwise or anti-clockwise. For example

a b
c d

rotated clockwise becomes

c a
d b

Can you obtain the following grid after 5 such rotations?

1 2 3
4 5 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First switch the parity of the $1$ and $4$, and the rest falls into place.
>
> ```
>  654
>  321
>  
>  625
>  314
>  
>  365
>  124
>  
>  326
>  145
>  
>  136
>  425
>  
>  123
>  456
> ```