# Rotating numbers in a 3x3 grid

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, computer-science

We have a 3x3 grid numbers like so

9 8 7
6 5 4
3 2 1

Four numbers in any 2x2 sub-grid can be rotated clockwise or anti-clockwise. For example

a b
c d

rotated clockwise becomes

c a
d b

Is it possible to make a series of such rotations to obtain the following grid?

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

**Bonus question:** if it is possible, then what is the fewest rotations required?

Here is a similar puzzle: [Rotating numbers in a 2x3 grid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/93773/rotating-numbers-in-a-2x3-grid)

Comment: Is there an intended 'aha moment' to solve this? If not, this seems more like a programming challenge than a puzzle.

Comment: Here we go again  I already said you may need a computer to solve it and added the computer tag. Yes I write puzzles that often require a computer to solve. Yes they are still puzzles and they still have aha moments to solve EVEN when you use a computer. Computer solutions can be just as difficult to come up with as manual ones. Now if you don't like such puzzles than that's your own personal choice, but others may like them. Can you please get off my back and not make comments every time.

Comment: There was a recent question for which I crafted a C program to solve it, in conjunction with making a cardboard rig to experiment with by shuffling the parts on squared paper. The accepted answer was numerically better, but the poster said "I used a nonlinear optimization solver" as though it was a tool available to mathematicians. So I can understand some people's aversion to a computer solution. In that case, I made everything (except the cardboard and the compiler) with my own hands and brain.

Comment: Yes, it's probably possible to optimize your algorithm in clever ways, but there don't appear to be any built-in "aha moments". It seems that brute force would work fine, and it doesn't look like there is an intended specific *path* to the solution -- and that solution path is what makes a "puzzle" different from a "challenge", in my eyes.

Comment: Just because it is possible to have ideas to make something easier, that doesn't make it a puzzle. Engineering problems are not puzzles even though you can have clever ideas about them -- because puzzles are *designed* with a specific solution in mind. It seems like the main thrust of this question is the programming, not any particular aha moment, which is why I think it is likely not a puzzle.

Comment: I'm not trying to put down these tasks - programming or engineering challenges can be fun in their own right (especially in video games like Infinifactory or SpaceChem). But I don't think they belong here if they're programming challenges rather than puzzles -- if 'aha moments' are *possible* but incidental, rather than being a core part of the design.

Comment: @Deusovi true, the issue did come up in a [comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92949/my-mothers-dish-collection/93130#comment266992_92949) in that puzzle.

Comment: How do you define an aha moment? It could be aha for one but not another person. How do you know if they are core or accidental?

Comment: By "core" or "accidental" I'm distinguishing whether the realizations are *built into* the puzzles, or if they occur by chance. What distinguishes a puzzle from a problem, in my eyes, is whether the solution path is *designed*. Questions like this don't seem to have an intentional chain of logic to the solution. It's *possible* that a solver could find a clever idea, but it's also possible that the only way to solve the question is with brute force. That makes it a programming problem, not a puzzle.

Comment: There is a previous question - [What is the strategy to solve Simon Tatham's Twiddle?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47124/what-is-the-strategy-to-solve-simon-tathams-twiddle) with a general solution.

Comment: The realizations could be built in the puzzle, but the solver may not find/use them. Similarly, they may NOT be built into the puzzle, but the solver does find them. While designing the problem you just don't know this. A puzzle may be intended as a programming problem, but solved by hand. Similarly it could be intended for manual solutions, but solved by a program. Again you don't know a priori which one it will be. Finally I don't see any issues with having programming puzzles - puzzles that are solved by a computer. Why are they such a problem for you?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis wow that's an impressive answer, thank you. Looks like they only show that a solution exists, but they don't show that it is the shortest. Still very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Playing with this in Simon Tatham's Twiddle, I quickly found a solution in

> 12 moves

One such sequence is

> D'CCAAD'AABBD'C

A different (more elegant?) solution:

> ADBCADBCADBC

The notation shouldn't be difficult to understand.

```
AB
CD
```

This is not necessarily the shortest solution.

With the aide of computer:

> 10 moves minimum: AAB'DB'CCA'BA'

Comment: Is the notation rotational or by row?

Comment: @JMP A is top-left, B is top-right, C is bottom-left and D is bottom-right. The apostrophe indicates CCW.

Comment: @DanielMathias I am also trying to solve the same problem for 4x4 and 5x5 squares. I would be quite interested to see what your method can get on those.

Comment: @Dmitry My method of enumeration (brute force) is not suitable for larger grids.

Comment: @Dmitry I have solutions for the 4x4 (32 moves) and 5x5 (62 moves), found manually.

Comment: @DanielMathias those are impressive results for manual work. I am now able to solve 4x4 with 24 moves and 5x5 with 54 moves. I am almost sure that they are optimal. I've started a sequence for this problem, so feel free to contribute: https://oeis.org/A330280

Answer (score 3):

The answer is

> 14

Notice that

> The initial configuration of numbers is rotated 180 degrees from the desired final configuration.

Also notice that

> the number 5 has to end up where it started from. Also, every rotation must involve the central number. So, each move of 5 away from the center must be matched by a move back. Any correct answer will be even.

The choice of starting rotation is arbitrary, but the rest of the moves will follow from that first choice. I started with rotating the lower left quartet clockwise.

> 9 8 7
>    **3** **6** 4
>    **2** **5** 1

(The highlighting shows the numbers that just moved.)

You then proceed

> by advancing around the square in a counterclockwise fashion. If your first move had rotated a quartet counterclockwise, you would proceed clockwise.

The next couple of moves are

> ```
> 9 8 7   9 5 8   3 9 8
> 3 5 6   3 6 7   6 5 7
> 2 1 4   2 1 4   2 1 4
> ```

Some more moves:

> ```
> 3 9 8   3 9 8   3 5 9   2 3 9
> 2 6 7   2 5 6   2 6 8   6 5 8
> 1 5 4   1 4 7   1 4 7   1 4 7
> ```

More moves:

> ```
> 2 3 9   2 3 9   2 5 3   1 2 3
> 1 6 8   1 5 6   1 6 9   6 5 9
> 4 5 7   4 7 8   4 7 8   4 7 8
> ```

And then:

> ```
> 1 2 3   1 2 3
> 4 6 9   4 5 6
> 7 5 8   7 8 9
> ```

What happens is

> each number creeps around the edge towards its final destination. Some are moved into the center, but moved back out again by the next move.

No computers were consulted.

Answer (score 1):

> $15$ (if you count CC as a single move). First put the $7$ in it's correct place, and align and position the $8$ and $9$:
>
> ```
>  987   945   945   945   945   235   235
>  654   678   681   361   328   498   461
>  321   321   372   782   716   716   789
> ```
>
> The $1$ and $4$ are manoeuvred into place, and the rest follows:
>
> ```
>  425   413   153   132
>  631   652   462   456
>  789   789   789   789
> ```
>
> And following @Magma's comment:
>
> ```
>  132   412   412   152   123
>  469   639   653   463   456
>  758   758   789   789   789
> ```
>
> Trying @Magma's comment from the first $789$ doesn't do anything:
>
> ```
>  235   425   425   165   165   635   623   163
>  461   631   619   249   234   124   145   425
>  789   789   738   738   789   789   789   789
> ```

Comment: Rotate bottom right CCW, top left CW, bottom right CW, top left CCW, then top right CCW. This swaps the top right and top middle cells.

Comment: @Magma; thanks - I didn't know that was possible!. Do you know why my second part doesn't work?

Comment: You're rotating twice in the third step?

Answer (score 0):

I don't normally post answers to my own questions, but I found a nice solution that improves on the best score. I can do it in

> 10 moves!

Here is the method:

> Each move is described with 3 values: row column direction. Row and column are 0-based indices of the top-left cell that we are rotating. CW is clockwise and CCW is counter-clockwise. Here is the solution
>
>  Original grid
>  987
>  654
>  321
>
>  move 1: 1 1 CCW
>  987
>  641
>  352
>
>  move 2: 1 0 CCW
>  987
>  451
>  632
>
>  move 3: 1 1 CCW
>  987
>  412
>  653
>
>  move 4: 1 0 CCW
>  987
>  152
>  463
>
>  move 5: 0 0 CW
>  197
>  582
>  463
>
>  move 6: 0 1 CCW
>  172
>  598
>  463
>
>  move 7: 1 1 CCW
>  172
>  583
>  496
>
>  move 8: 0 1 CCW
>  123
>  578
>  496
>
>  move 9: 1 1 CCW
>  123
>  586
>  479
>
>  move 10: 1 0 CW
>  123
>  456
>  789
>
>  I used a hill-climbing algorithm to find this. I'll describe it later if I have time.

Comment: I edited my answer five days ago...

Comment: I see now. Didn't notice it before.